# How to also remove whitespace with this regular expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, split

I am given a text (with punctuation marks) and I need to count how many times each word appears in it. I want to do this as follows: I want to separate the words from the other characters and then I want to create a frequency table. Here is my code:

```
import re
text=input("Input:")
space={''}
text=re.split("[. | , | ! | ?| |]", text)
sett=set(text)-space
frequency_table={}
for element in sett:
     frequency_table[element]=text.count(element)
print(frequency_table)
```

This does the trick, but my problem is that I cannot find a way to make my regular expresion remove whitespaces from the start. I found this pretty weird solution, but I don't know, it doesn't feel "right", there should be a way to also remove the whitespace with that regular expresion.
EDIT: Here is a sample input and a sample output:

```
Input: Bob?...Bob has many, many apples!... But you, how many apples do you have?
Output: Bob:2
        has:1
        many:3
        apples:2
        But:1
        you:2
        how:1
        do:1
        have:1
```

Note: The order of the words in the output doesn't matter, I don't care how they are sorted.

Comment: Can you include some sample input, along with the expected output.

Comment: @sushanth sure, I will include it right away.

Comment: "remove whitespaces from the start" - `text.lstrip()`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I haven't seen this function before, so I am not really sure how I should use it. I tried to put it above text=re.split("[. | , | ! | ?| |]", text), but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `text=re.split("[.,!? ]", text.lstrip())`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why don't you simply use `Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', text))` or `Counter(re.findall(r'[^\W_]+', text))`? Why do you have to deal with punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

Imo, you could use the opposite - define what a "word" is and use a defaultdict. This could be:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

# pattern and container
rx = re.compile(r'\b[-\w]+\b')
dd = defaultdict(int)

text = "Bob?...Bob has many, many apples!... But you, how many apples do you have?"

for word in rx.finditer(text):
    dd[word.group(0)] += 1
    
print(dd)
```

Which would result in

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'do': 1, 'many': 3, 'But': 1, 'how': 1, 'apples': 2, 'have': 1, 'Bob': 2, 'has': 1, 'you': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another solution you can try,

```
import re
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter

input_ = "Bob?...Bob has many, many apples!... But you, how many apples do you have?"

re_ = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(i) for i in punctuation))

for k, v in Counter(re_.sub(" ", input_).split()).items():
    print(k, v)
```

---

```
Bob 2
has 1
many 3
apples 2
...
...
```

Comment: thank you! This definitely works. Do you know how I could make that specific tweak I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

results = Counter(re.findall(r"[^\W_]+", "Bob?...Bob has many, many apples!... But you, how many apples do you have?"))
print(results)
```

**Results**: `Counter({'many': 3, 'Bob': 2, 'apples': 2, 'you': 2, 'has': 1, 'But': 1, 'how': 1, 'do': 1, 'have': 1})`

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##TY3NCsIwEITveYo1pxZLLp6loA/hwT9iu6WBNBs2G6VPH6tU8DID38cwcZaRwq4UN0ViAUY1ME3QkffYiaOQYFVHykGQlWJM2UuC/Q9VjGZwobfeV6zPt8vpft3qBvSBHq0xZikYbYLJhrn5JtgYPabNIuGQBWbKDYz0@pfQ04cvyye2uq5VZBekWt9rVcob).

`[^\W_]+` matches any character except non-word characters (all but `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`), `_` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)).